# Is there a common mime type that can be set to response.setContentType to handle all types of file?

Tags: java, servlets, file-upload, mime-types

I need to open the uploaded files in browser. The files could be of any type like txt,doc,xls,pdf,jpeg due to which i can't set any particular mime type using "response.setContentType". So what i want to know is if there is any common mime type to handle all kinds of file? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20163864/what-mime-type-to-use-as-general-purpose

Answer (score 2):

The whole point of MIME types is to say what *kind* of data you're sending back.

The closest I can think of is `application/octet-stream`, which basically means "a bunch of bytes" (see [RFC2046](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046.txt)), although that might be more misleading to the browser than not including a `Content-Type` at all.

You can combine this with `Content-Disposition: inline` to suggest to the browser to attempt to display it rather than offering to save it. (See [RFC2183](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2183.txt).) Whether the browser actually tries to do that is up to the browser.

I would experiment with target browsers with no `Content-Type` (but with `Content-Disposition: inline`) and with `application/octet-stream` and `Content-Disposition: inline` to see whether one or the other suits your needs.

Comment: Tried with application/octet-stream and Content-Disposition: inline but couldn't make it work. The images are getting opened alright but the texts and pdf's aren't.

Comment: @Shivayan: Did you try `Content-Disposition` *without* specifying any content type? (That's one of the suggestions above.)