# Is it possible to specify swagger consumes to any?

Tags: swagger

The title contains my whole question. How do you specify consumes property in swagger when the endpoint accept any type.

For example, Here in [OneDrive simple file upload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_put_content#example-upload-a-new-file).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`application/octet-steam` is the [general MIME type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20163864/113116) that means "unknown binary data".

```yaml
consumes:
  - application/octet-stream
```

Similarly, if the server can *return* any MIME type, you can use the wildcard MIME type `*/*` for `produces`:

```yaml
produces:
  - '*/*'

# This corresponds to the request header:
# Accept: */*
```